# Maven/import basics - cannot find classes

Tags: java, json, maven, import

Using the following in my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.json</groupId>
  <artifactId>json</artifactId>
  <version>20170516</version>
</dependency>
```

Yet the json classes I am interested in are not recognized in my code (e.g., JSONArray.)  Then I attempted an import:

```
import org.json.*;
```

In this case everything compiles but I get the following when I run the code:

```
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONArray
```

I seem to find references that indicate I need a json.jar in my classpath, but should that really be necessary with the established maven dependencies (my preferred solution) or the import call?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need json.jar in your classpath. It is usually downloaded from the maven repository into you m2 folder. The m2 folder should then be in your classpath.

How do you build your maven project, mvn clean install?

Comment: My project is in IntelliJ - it is defined as a "maven project" in that context.  I don't see an m2 folder anywhere in the project.  I tried re-importing the pom.xml to no avail.

Comment: What OS are you running. The m2 folder (linux/MacOS) is located at ~/.m2 Not sure on Windows. But I do think that when you run a maven project through IntelliJ or any other IDE they should download the dependencies.

Comment: MacOS - thanks, I did locate it:

`R0229283:.m2 afs01$ tree | grep json
    │   ├── json
    │   │   └── json
    │   │           ├── json-20170516.jar
    │   │           ├── json-20170516.jar.sha1
    │   │           ├── json-20170516.pom
    │   │           └── json-20170516.pom.sha1`

I'll try adding it to the classpath.

Comment: Thanks, that worked.  I'm still not understanding what Maven brings to the table in this instance, though.

Answer (score 1):

It totally depends on your project packaging type .

1. If it is a JAR - you are responsible to provide dependency jars for run time. It can be done in multiple ways as for any Java applications: through CLASSPATH environment, -cp parameter for JVM, define locations in your JAR file MANIFEST file or by creation of one fat jar with all dependencies in it.

*(note: if you use IDE like Eclipse - it does it for you when you ran your code in it. It includes all Maven dependencies into run class path. But not for real runtime outside of IDE).*

2. If it is a WAR or EAR all dependencies with scope `compile` or `runtime` will be included into WAR/EAR file and will be available for your code. But if scope is `provided` - it goes back to the same as for JAR. `provided` scope is useful when needed dependency is in Application Server class path where WAR/EAR will run. It prevents to package common dependencies in each and every WAR/EAR and possible version conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was going on the IntelliJ Maven side menu, right clicking on the project and choosing the option **Reimport**